# Output what Rspec "sees" to an HTML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this RSpec test that used to pass. Now it doesn't and I can't see why.

In order to localize the problem, I was wondering whether there is a way to output to an HTML file what RSpec actually "sees". In other words, if I have:

```rb
before do
    #Create data here
    #
    #
    #sign user in here
    visit root_path
end
```

I would like to take the rendering of that `root_path` and write it to an HTML file, so I can inspect it manually via web browser.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use 'save_and_open_page'. You may need to add 'launchy' to your gemfile. Once you do:

```
before do
    #Create data here
    #
    #
    #sign user in here
    visit root_path
    save_and_open_page
end
```

More: http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/ever-heard-of-capybaras-save_and_open_page-method/

Comment: Thank you! I was actually just reading about it here too http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/   : D great!